# Is a twisted whisker (for a cat) dangerous?

Tags: cats

One of the whiskers of my cat got twisted (I don't know how she got it).

Is it something to worry about?
Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your cat does not normally have twisted or fragile whiskers (a few certain breeds do), the whisker may be a little uncomfortable but will regrow and the old will fall out within a few weeks.

You do not need to do anything (unless the whisker is close to the eye and is irritating it).  Whiskers are very, very sensitive.  They give the cat much information about its environment.  Your kitty will not appreciate you messing with this sensitive part of her anatomy.

Since it is only one whisker, she should compensate with her other whiskers when it comes to balance and examining her environment.   You don't say if your cat stays inside.   As a precaution, you will need to keep your cat inside while the whisker falls out and grows back.  This is to prevent her from misjudging her environment.  (Although, I hope you always keep your kitty inside!)

So, don't worry!   Cat's are curious creatures.  Unfortunately, their curiosity may often cost them a whisker.  Fortunately, the problem rectifies itself.

NOTE:  If you start to see curly whiskers more often, you likely have a kitty whose whiskers natural curl.  Again, nothing to worry about.

Comment: The cat is only inside :)

Comment: @Eyal Good for you! 